# Histogram Matching with ROI

Tags: opencv, histogram

I made a code to segment a video from non-static camera to moving and non-moving objects, of course the mask will not be 100% accurate. but I am ok with the result.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwTxD.png

what I need now is histogram matching to detect the moving object which is in one of  those spots.

How could I do that?

[my code will handle the object when it's not moving]